# simple jquery slider - (1) Reverse slide direction and (2) Chrome compatible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I have a very simple jquery slider that rotates `<li>` elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/cQdTq/9/

Issue #1: I can't figure out how to reverse the sliding direction. Currently slides bottom to top, and I'd like to slide top to bottom.

Issue #2: When run in JSFiddle, it doesn't keep cycling through in CHROME (only cycles once and stops).  FireFox and IE work ok.  When I run in a different simulator (codepen.io), it seems to work in Chrome.

Issue #3: (because I'm supper jquery newbie) what exactly do I need to put in the HTML file to call the script, and what should I name the script file?

Code:

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
  <ul>
    <li>slide 1</li>
    <li>slide 2</li>
    <li>slide 3</li>
    <li>slide 4</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

      setInterval(function () {
        move();
    }, 1500);


    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();

    function move() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({bottom: - slideHeight}, 1000, function () {
        $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
        $('#slider ul').css('bottom', '');
        });
    };

});
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #888;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background:#fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: Edited with code in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

**to run in Chrome**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

     var interval = setInterval(function () {
        move();
    }, 1500);


    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();

    function move() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            top: - slideHeight
        }, 1500, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('top', '');
        });
    };

});
```

test that code [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/cQdTq/12/)

to use javascript in html [click here](http://www.simplehtmlguide.com/javascript.php)

Comment: And explanation would be helpful. Also while you seem to have the animation working, you don't having it moving in the direction the OP requested.

Comment: That works in chrome.  I also played some more and found this to work in chrome also: http://jsfiddle.net/S4SmM/356/